# in shell, how to get every argument that contains spaces

Tags: linux, shell

The arguments are separated using spaces:

```
sh test.sh "a b c "
```

In the `test.sh`, how should you use a `for` loop to get the argument `a b c`?

Comment: why do you need a for loop?

Comment: It would be clearer if you had a second argument -- for instance, `"a b c" "d e f"` -- and specified how you wanted _that_ one handled. If you would iterate over the two arguments in that case, the first example in the answer by @JonathanLeffler is perfect, and I'm unclear on why it hasn't been accepted yet.

Answer (score 1):

As a single argument:

```
for i in "$@"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

As separate arguments:

```
for i in $*  # Or $@
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

And if you invoke:

```
./test.sh a b c
```

but you want all three arguments treated as one, then:

```
for i in "$*"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

(The loop is really not needed; `echo "$*"` would do the job.)

Answer (score 0):

Even this will do:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
for i; do
    echo :$i:
done
```

This is equivalent to: `for i in "$@"; do ...`

So you will get:

```
$ sh script.sh 'a b c '
:a b c :
```